# Browser cache after server missconfiguration

Tags: php, symfony1, browser-cache

On a symfony production server, an automatic update has uninstalled libapache2-mod-php5. So after that, whenever you try to access a website page, it downloads the index.php file as text:

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

    $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
    sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

[This ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1361019) shows how to reinstall libapache2-mod-php5 to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now if I open the website in another browser, it works fine. However, chrome kept the broken version in his cache, **and when I access the fixed website, it still downloads index.php** instead of showing the homepage.

Obviously, I would like to avoid having to say to customers "clear your cookies and your browsing history"... Do you have a server-side solution to force the browser not to use his cache ?

Note: clearing the Symfony cache doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the browser never sends a request to the server. So there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Is there a way with Symfony I can test that the server receives a request at all ? Do you know some online resources about how client caching works ?

Comment: The server doesn't receives the request indeed. I've tested with a file_put_contents() in index.php.